# How to retrive imageid and insert it into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a INSERT function where it inserts the image filename in the 'ImageFile' field in the "Image" table, each row has it's own ImageId thanks to auto number. An example of this is below:

```
ImageId    ImageFile

23         orange.jpg
24         flowers.png
25         castle.png
26         orange.jpg
```

What I want to do is also insert the ImageId into another table with the QuestionId and SessionId so that this table (Image_Question) can use the ImageId to link the Image table with the Image Question table. But how do I code it so that when I insert image details in the table above, then it will retrieve it's ImageId and also store it in the ImageId in the Image_Question table. Example below:

```
ImageId   SessionId  QuestionId

23        AAA        1
24        AAA        2
25        AAA        3
26        AAA        4
```

I have coded the INSERT values for SessionId and QuestionId but just need help retrieving and inserting the ImageId. Below is the current code:

```
<?php

session_start();


//connect to db

$i = 0;

$insertimage = array();

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){


    $insertimage[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . 
                    ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". 
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] ) ."'";

}


 $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
    VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertimage) . ")";

echo($imagesql);

mysql_close();


?>
```

I have an old php version 5.2.13 because that is the version of the university's server so I have to use mysql() code even though I know it is better to use PDO or Mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [mysql_insert_id](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) . It will return the id of last inserted row, so you can assign it to variable and use that varriable to insert the id into another table with next query

Comment: I will give it a go and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

You have no comma between ImageId and SessionId

```
$insertimage[] = "'". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . "', '" .
                ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". 
                mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] ) ."'";
```

Also if the Id's are numeric, drop the single quotes (in this case you don't need `mysql_real_escape_string` either, just verify the input is numeric with [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and not a float with [`is_float()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)):

```
$insertimage[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . ", " .
                ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ." ,". 
                mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Question 
             (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
             VALUES 
             ((SELECT ImageId FROM image ORDER BY ImageId DESC LIMIT 1),
              " . implode('), (', $insertimage) . ")";
```