# Why Data is not getting inserted into the mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a INSERT function where it inserts the image filename in the 'ImageFile' field in the "Image" table, each row has it's own ImageId thanks to auto number. An example of this is below:

```
ImageId    ImageFile

23         orange.jpg
24         flowers.png
25         castle.png
26         orange.jpg
```

What I want to do is also insert the ImageId into another table with the QuestionId and SessionId so that this table (Image_Question) can use the ImageId to link the Image table with the Image Question table. Now I am trying to use mysql_insert_id to retrieve the ImageId from the Image Table and store it in the ImageId in the Image_Question table.

But I can't seem to figure out what I need to do, at the moment the the INSERTING values into the Image Table is working fine but it does not insert any values inside the Image_Question table.

So my question is for each row inserted into the Image table, how do I retrieve the ImageId from the Image Table after it has been inserted into the Image Table, and insert it into the Image_Question table using mysql_insert_id()?
Example below:

```
ImageId   SessionId  QuestionId

23        AAA        1
24        AAA        2
25        AAA        3
26        AAA        4
```

I have coded the INSERT values for SessionId and QuestionId but just need help retrieving and inserting the ImageId. Below is the current code:

```
      <?php

        session_start();


        //connect to db

        $result = 0;
        $i = 0;
        $insertimage = array();


                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){


    $insertimage[] = "'". 
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] ) . 
                    ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') ."' ,'". 
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] ) ."'";

}

    $imageinsertsql .= "INSERT INTO Image_Question 
         (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
         VALUES 
         ((SELECT ImageId FROM Image ORDER BY ImageId DESC LIMIT 1),
          " . implode('), (', $insertimage) . ")";

          mysql_query($imageinsertsql);

              }

              mysql_close();

        ?>
```

I have an old php version 5.2.13 because that is the version of the university's server.

Comment: i thought this is solved here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915022/how-to-retrive-imageid-and-insert-it-into-another-table/10915261#10915261

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve ImageId from one db table and store it in another db table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924346/how-to-retrieve-imageid-from-one-db-table-and-store-it-in-another-db-table)

Comment: When you ask a "not working" type of question please post any error messages that you get. You need to enable PHP error reporting/logging settings such as `display_errors` if you don't see an error.

Comment: you can use mysql trigger to update second table with id from first table refer [mysql refrence maual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: so does it go SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID($lastimageid);? or SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(ImageId)?

Comment: `while ($someArray) {
 $res = mysql_query('INSERT INTO ImagesTable SET imageName = "karumburum.jpg"');
 $id = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();');
 $res2 = mysql_query('INSERT INTO OtherTable SET imageId = '.$id.', otherColumn = "'.$somedata.'"');
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `ImageId` to the `VALUES` clause of each record being inserted into the `Image_Question` table.  Using PHP's [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function, one could adjust your `for` loop as follows:

```
for ($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++) {
  $insertimage[] = mysql_insert_id()
  .", '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'] )
        .($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '') . "'"
  .", '". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['numQuestion'][$i] ) . "'";
}

$imageinsertsql .= "INSERT INTO Image_Question 
  (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
  VALUES 
  (" . implode('), (', $insertimage) . ")";
```

However, the ancient MySQL extension is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799); you can use instead either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer, which both support [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041) into which variables can be passed as parameters (that do not get evaluated for SQL and therefore do not need to be escaped).  For example, using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

$qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)');
$qry->execute(array("ImageFiles/{$_FILES['fileImage']['name']})"));

$qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
                      VALUES (:ImageId, :SessionId, :QuestionId)');

$qry->bindValue(':ImageId', $dbh->lastInsertId());
$qry->bindValue(':SessionId', $_SESSION['id'] .
                 ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '')
               );

$qid = null;
$qry->bindParam(':QuestionId', $qid);
foreach ($_POST['numQuestion'] as $qid) $qry->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query.

```
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Question 
         (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId) 
         VALUES 
         ((SELECT ImageId FROM image ORDER BY ImageId DESC LIMIT 1),
          " . implode('), (', $insertimage) . ")";
```

Comment: Do I not need `$lastimageid = mysql_insert_id();`?

Comment: I still can't get it to insert data into the Image_Question table, I have updated code which includes your query, I have found out you have just said that mysql_insert_id() is needed, so my question is where do I place the mysql_insert_id() code in my code and why do you think it is not inserting data into database? (I have checked query and there is no speliing mistakes in either query)

Comment: This answer is a terrible idea: it is not concurrency safe!  If another connection inserts into `image` before the above insert into `Question` takes place, the wrong association will be made.

Comment: sorry bout that you do not need `$lastimageid = mysql_insert_id();` this anymore. just this query will do.

Comment: @eggyal: if thats the case, same thing happens if you choose `mysql_insert_id();` so what do you think is the proper way?

Comment: @sephoy08: No, `mysql_insert_id()` returns the last auto_incremented value *on the current connection* - so other concurrent connections have no effect upon it.